# Vim Tabularize by //

Tags: vim, tabular

How do you align comments by `//` with Vim Tabular plugin?

```
double n; // number of steps
double np; // number of particles
double q; // probability of success
```

I know that it's easy to align by, i.e., `=` like this `:Tab /=`. But `:Tab / //` adds a space between `/`'s and it stops to be a comment any more:

```
double n;  /  / number of steps
double np; /  / number of particles
double q;  /  / probability of success
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`:Tabularize / \/\/` seems to work.

Here we are escaping the slashes.